# How to polyfill or mock global (window) navigator using Next.js + Babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, next.js, es6-modules

We're using a third party's `node_module`, which is expecting to find a global `navigator.useragent` that doesn't exist in node's server-side rendering environment.

Generally, for our own packages, we `import { window } from '../utils/globals'` if using `window` functionality, but we don't have the ability to edit this `node_module`.

I'm not sure how to automatically provide `window.navigator` for this specific package (or all packages), and it doesn't look like we're using Webpack, but rather yarn/next/babel.

How would I go about creating a global variable during the compilation/transpilation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a global / context variable before `_app.jsx` class definition.

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
if (typeof global.navigator === 'undefined') global.navigator = {};
// const navigator = {};

class MyApp extends App {
    // ...
}
```

I tried adding it where we import the offending package, but that didn't work. Not sure on the specifics of server-side/client-side rendering handoff, and there's probably a more refined, tailored way to handle the situation.